# Class is unable to be recognized by other classes and form within same project and name space

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

I have a public abstract class employee with a constructor I would like to call from a click event in the form for the project. When trying to call the method I get an error that this type or namespace cannot be found, I also get this error if trying to call it from another class within the same project and name space.

Here is the Employee class I have:

```
using System;
using andrewWoodsAssignment2;
namespace andrewWoodsAssignment2
{


    abstract class Employee
    {
        string employeeFirstName;
        string employeeLastName;
        string employeeNumber;
        string employeeAddress;

        public Employee(string first, string last, string number, string address)
        {
            employeeFirstName = first;
            employeeLastName = last;
            employeeNumber = number;
            employeeAddress = address;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "";
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my form I am trying to call the instructor in:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using andrewWoodsAssignment2;

namespace andrewWoodsAssignment2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee e1 = new Employee("f", "f", "f", "f");
        }
    }
}
```

The line in the button1_click is the one causing the error, I have tried checking namespaces, and class names

Here is another class that inherits the employee class which also can't call the constructor or even seem to recognize the inheritance:

```
using System;
using andrewWoodsAssignment2;
namespace andrewWoodsAssignment2
{


    public class ShiftSupervisor : Employee
    {

        double annualSalary;
        double annualBonus;
        int minimumHoursTraining;
        int trainingHoursAttended;

        public ShiftSupervisor(double annualSalary, double annualBonus, int minimumHoursTraining,
            int trainingHoursAttended)
        {
            
            this.annualSalary = annualSalary;
            this.annualBonus = annualBonus;
            this.minimumHoursTraining = minimumHoursTraining;
            this.trainingHoursAttended = trainingHoursAttended;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

What could be causing this?
Here is a screenshot of my files in visual studio

[image]

Comment: Doesn't your IDE show the errors? The `Employee e1 = new Employee("f", "f", "f", "f");` should have a line explaining that you can't instantiate an abstract class directly, you're supposed to instantiate it's non-abstract derivatives (ie, ShiftSupervisor ). Then, the constructor for your ShiftSupervisor would point out the argument doesn't match, because Employee's constructor signature is (string,string,string,string) while ShiftSupervisor is (double,double,int,int), you must match the parameter types and order.

Comment: @MostafaMohamedAhmed The default access for classes in C# is `internal`. So, this is not the problem in this question as long as all the source files are in the same project.

Comment: @AndrewWoods Are all these source files part of the same Visual Studio project? Can you show us the list of files in the project from your Visual Studio as a screenshot?

Comment: @MostafaMohamedAhmed could you please point out why you expect "Assignment" to be removed from the question/code? To my (granted limited) knowledge it is perfectly fine to ask about homework as long as enough information is shown. Obvioulsy lack of effort/clarity may cause downvotes, but presence of "Assignment" by itself never was a problem on SO...

Comment: @NineBerry I've added a screenshot to the post, I believe they are in the same project. My classes are public but I am still unable to call constructors even if I try creating a ShiftSupervisor object, or a ShiftSupervisor object of the Employee type.

Comment: Have you set Employee as public? As in, `public abstract class Employee`, or inversely, just remove the public declaration from `ShiftSupervisor `. Then, write a correct constructor in ShiftSupervisor that matches the Employee constructor signature.

Comment: Move all `*.cs files` from `Solution Items` folder to `andrewWoodsAssignment2 Project`, Then right click on `andrewWoodsAssignment2 Project` > select `Sync Namespace`. Then select menu `Build` > `Rebuild Solution`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files listed under "Solution Items" are not part of your project. Move them into your project using drag n drop.

You will still get compiler errors because of other issues with your code, but the visibility issue will be solved.